# find first and last date of the last month

Tags: java, datetime, utc

I have a simple but tricky code to write where I have given the date String of today in UTC time.

```
String s = Instant.now().toString().replaceAll("T.*", "");
```

I need to find the first and last days of the last month and store them in separate Strings. Any advice on how to achieve it best?

Comment: Dont use strings but dates for starters.

Comment: `LocalDate.now()`?

Comment: Please include sample data, and explain why  you can't just use now() as suggested, and also expected output.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I use the `import java.time.*` and don't want to mix up with many libraries. Besides, I need to be careful to know the current `UTC` date and find the first + last date of the last month.  Ok, I just find they are indeed in the same library `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Indeed, a duplicate... not sure why I don't get that in the Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the month before the current date then use the below code:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);  // Retrieve the date now
LocalDate lastMonth = today.minus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS); // Retrieve the date a month from now
System.out.println("First day: " + lastMonth.withDayOfMonth(1)); // retrieve the first date
System.out.println("Last day: " + lastMonth.withDayOfMonth(lastMonth.lengthOfMonth())); // retrieve the last date
```

Comment: I would like to use `LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);` to set the `UTC` time.

Comment: @Arefe I have edited the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).

If you don't have to start with a string, don't. Start with a `LocalDate` if possible.

If you have to start with a string, you can convert your string `s` to a `LocalDate` by `parse`:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(s);
```

Now we can get the start and end of the month like this:

```
LocalDate startOfMonth = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate endOfMonth = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

I suggest you not to convert them to strings until the absolutely necessary (like you display it to the user).

Answer (score 4):

You can get using `LocalDate`

```
LocalDate startOfMonth = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate endOfMonth = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: This code invokes the current date and gets the first day of the current month. The question is asking for the "LAST" month.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple when using `LocalDate` and its date arithmetic functions:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate firstDayOfCurrentMonth = now.withDayOfMonth(1);

LocalDate firstDayOfLastMonth = firstDayOfCurrentMonth.minusMonths(1);
LocalDate lastDayOfLastMonth = firstDayOfCurrentMonth.minusDays(1);
```